# Can't display variable data in HTML - Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to display the username of a logged in user in my HTML. I am using firebase for authentication purposes and Angular 8 for the main development. Firebase integration is fully supported and causes no problems. But when I try to display the data fetched from firebase user name, I can't do so.

I have done a lot of Google searches, including reading the Angular CLI documentation and also looking at various previous questions asked on stackoverflow but I can't seem to figure it, somehow. This is my code:

```js
export class PortalComponent implements OnInit {

  public username: string = null;

  constructor() {

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.username = user.displayName;
      }
    });

  }
}
```

And this is my HTML code:

```html
<h2>Welcome {{username}}!</h2>
```

How do I fix this? My expected answer should be something like `Welcome Brian!`

**EDIT:**

I looked at a lot of answers and most of them are correct implementations, however I am not sure why this is not working. I am still looking for answers with complete angular implementation but for the moment I used jQuery and it works. What I did:

*Updated HTML:*

```html
<h2>Welcome <span id="username"></span>!</h2>
```

*Updated TypeScript:*

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

// Code removed for brevity

export class PortalComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        $('#username').html(user.displayName);
      }
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: what you get in `user`?

Comment: What do you see?  Is there an error, or just nothing? Do you see the user object if you console.log?

Comment: @dgabriel I get the correct username when I console log `user.displayName` But my html is just nothing.

Comment: *ngIf='username' check should fix this

Comment: Initilaize this way `public username: string = 'Test';` if you see test your function doesnt run

Comment: Seems like it's a problem related to the async nature of Javascript?

Comment: @dgabriel That does not help!

Comment: @dota2pro you have set the value of username before even it was changed and used it in html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm assuming you will be adding more than a Username in the future I recommend you tweak your code to use a service. I works the same way but is more flexible when working with larger data.

**user.service.ts:**

```
 export class UserService {
   constructor() {}
   username: string;

   getUsername() {
     return this.username;
   }
   setUsername(user) {
     this.username = user;
   }
}
```

**Your component Updated:**

```
 export class PortalComponent implements OnInit {

   username: string; //Setting null is unnecessary 
   userService: UserService;
   constructor(private _userService: UserService) {
     this.userService= _userService;
     firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
       if (user) {
         this.userService.setUsername(user);
       }
     });
   }
   get GetUsername(): string
   {
     return this.userService.getUsername();
   }
}
```

**Componenent html:**

```
 <div *ngIf="this.GetUsername()">
   <h2>Welcome{{ this.GetUsername() }}!</h2>
 </div>
```

Comment: Gives an error as `ERROR TypeError: _co.GetUsername is not a function`

Comment: Yah, I messed up lol. Get rid of the GetUsername  function in the component and change the this.GetUsername()  in html to  <h2>{{ this.userService.getUsername() }}!</h2>

Comment: Error is gone and now it does not work. I can only see `Welcome !` instead of `Welcome Brian!`. I can get my user to console log and it works, so I guess firebase is returning an user, it's just Angular is not displaying it!

Comment: Hmmm, I even added a delay in my code (setTimeout) to accommodate for firebase response time. I'm not sure without seeing your code as it could be anything.

Comment: Should I recreate this on stackblitz or you can do a private message to me and I will share the screenshots

Comment: Either one works. I'm not sure how to send a private message to you other than using stackExchange

Comment: I have edited the question. Your answer works on Stackblitz and I am marking it as an answer. However, I am still unable to get the output on my computer and used an alternative (See the edited question)

Comment: Sorry this response is kind of late lol. Your edit works and is a good idea. The service pretty much does the same thing but since it's not working for you jquery is another great option. It's obvious that the bind to the h2 is not being updated through angular so maybe you have an outdated angular version or something (you can update all packages with "npm update"). You could also try deleting your node_module folder and resintalling it with "npm install" If you don't  care about  using angular 100% of the time jquery is a good fix.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use a get method for these cases. Try something like this:

```
export class PortalComponent implements OnInit {

  public username: string = null;

  constructor() {

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.username = user.displayName;
      }
    });
  }
  get GetUserName(): string {
     return this.username;
  }
}
```

```
<h2>Welcome {{GetUserName}}!</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

using *ngIf

The DOM will populate only when the data is ready.

```
<div *ngIf='username'>
<h1>{{username}}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I lost the contents of the div too!

Comment: You didn't lost the content, it's just that the operation is async and by the time that finishes the html is rendered, with ngIf it will only be rendered if available

Comment: I never renders

Comment: Did you console log user, is user present?

Comment: User is an object. user is present there as I can see by the `console.log(user)` statement in my code, it returns an object with different properties attached to it. Thanks for your suggestion though!

Comment: If there's a property named displayName present in the user object that should show value, try using async pipe with value

Comment: Yes there is a property called displayName

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is caused due to context of this variable being different in the function.

```
export class PortalComponent implements OnInit {
  public username: string = null;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(setUsername);
  }

  private setUserName(user) {
      if (user) {
        this.username = user.displayName;
      }
  }
}
```

I think the above code should resolve the issue